# simulator crashes when assigning value to a UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have this code that for some reason is crashing whenever I try to change the text of a label.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Subs" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary * modelDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSDictionary * yearDict = [modelDict valueForKey:Sub_Model];
    for (NSString * yearKey in yearDict) {
        NSDictionary * sizeDict = [yearDict valueForKey:yearKey];
        mount_depth = round([[[sizeDict valueForKey:Sub_Size] objectForKey:@"Mounting Depth"] floatValue]);
        displacement = round([[[sizeDict valueForKey:Sub_Size] objectForKey:@"Displacement"] floatValue]);
        sealed_min = [[[sizeDict valueForKey:Sub_Size] objectForKey:@"Sealed Min."] floatValue];
        sealed_max = [[[sizeDict valueForKey:Sub_Size] objectForKey:@"Sealed Max."] floatValue];
        ported_min = [[[sizeDict valueForKey:Sub_Size] objectForKey:@"Ported Min."] floatValue];
        ported_max = [[[sizeDict valueForKey:Sub_Size] objectForKey:@"Ported Max."] floatValue];
        minportlen = [[sizeDict valueForKey:Sub_Size] objectForKey:@"Min. Port Len."];
        maxportlen = [[sizeDict valueForKey:Sub_Size] objectForKey:@"Max. Port Len."];
    }
    // [self loadEnclosure];
    portlenLbl.hidden = FALSE;
}
```

Then I have a segmented control on a navigation item to change the labels according to what the user selects and whenever they select the non default one is when the program crashes.

```
- (IBAction) boxSize:(id)sender {
    // [self loadEnclosure];
    switch (self.boxControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            portlenLbl.text = (@"%@", minportlen);
            break;
        case 1:
            portlenLbl.text = (@"%@", maxportlen);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I should also add that there are multiple views before getting to this point and they 're called using methods similar to this:

```
- (IBAction) GetBox:(id)sender {
    K_Box * KView = [[K_Box alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    KView.Num_Subs = self.Num_Subs;
    KView.Box_Type = self.Box_Type;
    KView.Box_Shape = self.Box_Shape;
    KView.Sub_Model = self.Sub_Model;
    KView.Sub_Size = self.Sub_Size;
    [self presentModalViewController:KView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: arr not enough reputation to edit the post. Please use the code tag and align it a bit more accurate. //EDIT: thanks @aBitObvious

Comment: Yeah, I was editing it when you posted that as I saw it came out funky.  Sorry.

Comment: have yor realized, that there is a live-preview?

Comment: And I was editing while you guys were editing. :)

Comment: sorry but thats too funny, three or four people editing the same post :'D

Comment: Yes, but wasn't paying attention at the time.  My apologies, I will use more care with my future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your real problem is here:**

```
minportlen = [[sizeDict valueForKey:Sub_Size] objectForKey:@"Min. Port Len."];
maxportlen = [[sizeDict valueForKey:Sub_Size] objectForKey:@"Max. Port Len."];
```

`objectForKey:` returns an autoreleased object, which you are assigning directly to your instance variable. By the time your app reaches the `boxSize:` method, those values are out of scope because they were drained from the autorelease pool that managed them. So the solution is to simply `retain` the return value of `objectForKey:` and then directly assign that to your instance variable:

```
minportlen = [[[sizeDict valueForKey:Sub_Size] objectForKey:@"Min. Port Len."] retain];           
maxportlen = [[[sizeDict valueForKey:Sub_Size] objectForKey:@"Max. Port Len."] retain];
```

(Of course, if you defined your instance variable as a property, you should use the designated property setters instead.)

Comment: or [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", maxportlen]; if he like to apply a format ,) // yep I know, I only comment some posts for completeness ^^ I have fun doing that :p

Comment: @iPortable Yes, but it doesn't appear that the OP wants to.

Comment: There was originally more text involved, but I removed it for debugging.  Doing it this way still crashes.

Comment: When I declared minportlen and maxportlen in the header files I have them set as @property(nonatomic, retain) is this the same as the above?

Comment: @Ian Oswald You are doing direct instance variable assignment, which doesn't do anything to the assigned value, so you can either use my solution or use the property setters via `self`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it's working using your solution.

Comment: @Jacob My philosophy is that if you're retaining those properties, take advantage of the objects (NSStrings) you've created for the purpose and use `self.`. Otherwise there's no reason to even create the properties.

Comment: @Matthew Frederick I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use portlenLbl.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", maxportlen];  .
And do remember that whenever setting  label text use the above syntax.

Comment: Still having the same issue using this assignment.

Comment: Using `stringWithFormat:@"%@"` for an object that's already an NSString is needless overhead -- there is no format, so why make the device evaluate the formatting string?